# Multiple Models in the single View (django, python)

Tags: python, django

.Hello everyone! I am a beginner in Django and I know that this question was asked hundrets of times on SO, but I still can't get it. I tried to use two models in the same IndexView, but it just repeats the elements which contains in the **Petition** model.

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'home_list'
    model = Petition

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['petition'] = Petition.objects.all()
        context['law'] = Law.objects.all()

        return context
```

And here is a relevant part of the template:

```
    {% if home_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for petition in home_list%}
        <li><a href="/petitions/{{ petition.id }}/">{{ petition.question }}</a></li>



        <img src="{{ petition.image.url }}" height="200" width="300">

    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No petitions are available.</p>
{% endif %}


{% if home_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for law in home_list %}
        <li><a href="/laws/{{ law.id }}/">{{ law.question }}</a></li>



        <img src="{{ law.image.url }}" height="200" width="300">

    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No laws are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're defining your `law` list in the context as law but then you never reference it, you should be looping over these instead of `home_list`

```
{% if law %}
{% for l in law %}  {# law is already defined so cant be used as scope var #}
```

Comment: What is said is all correct, but also make sure to name your context variables meaningfully, for example "laws" or "law_list" and "petitions" or "petition_list" if you assign querysets to them.

Comment: @AidasBendoraitis - I agree, I was trying to keep this simple to avoid changing too many things but descriptive variables are a good idea.

Comment: Guys, thank you!  I didn't expect that it was so simple